# Is this how Java package imports are supposed to work?

Tags: java, import, package

I've been struggling with my first regex. During the compile, `Pattern` and `Matcher` kept getting `cannot find symbol` errors.

I just changed `import java.util.*` to `import java.util.regex.*` and it works like a dream.

I was under the impression that `import`ing `java.util.*` would *also* bring in `java.util.*.*` etc. Is that not the case? I can't find any documentation that addresses this specific question....

Comment: So what are some reasons that regex classes can't be found during compile, but CAN be found once I explicitly import the regex package(s)?

Comment: @dwwilson66: they CAN be found, but Java avoids recursive imports (which bloat binary size) by making you explicitly import packages. Which is certainly not a bad idea.

Comment: Lets look at is like boxes. Utilities is a box (java.util), with some stuff in it (classes), and some boxes (subpackages). If you just open (import)the Utilities box, you cant get the stuff inside the boxes in it yet (the classes in the subpackages), you still have to open (import) them.

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern` matches `java.util.regex.*` but not `java.util.*`.  You could just use Eclipse's Ctrl-Shift-O to organize your imports for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is how package imports work (and are supposed to work) in Java. For example, doing `import javax.swing.*;` will import all *classes* within `javax.swing.*` but **not** sub-packages and their classes.

Ergo, `javax.swing.*` will **not** import `javax.swing.event` or `javax.swing.event.*`

Read the [following blog](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2008/06/import-statements.html) for some friendly newbie advice.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the blog link. That should be in texbooks somewhere... |:

Comment: @dwwilson66 maybe your book lacks of proper explanation about Java language.

Answer (score 9):

No, package imports only get the direct classes in that package (java.* will not import everything, only ones such as Java.SomeClass, not java.util.SomeClass)

Answer (score 5):

Importing `java.util.*` *will not* import `java.util.*.*`.

Comment: Is there a way to import ```java.util.*.*```? That doesn't compile.

Comment: @Siddhartha Unfortunately no, you'll need to individually wildcard import any sub-packages.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

See a link and a quoted excerpt from the link below.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

> Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package,
>   but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other
>   java.awt.xxxx packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types
>   in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both
>   packages with all their files:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
```