# Shouldn't "import foo.*" also include subpackage "foo.bar.*"?

Tags: java, oop, import, package

Studying Java, I've thought about a, to me, rather confusing property of many tutorials. Consider the following two imports from a sample tutorial:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

The first line obviously imports the java.awt package, and the second one awt's subpackage. **But shouldn't the asterix include all sub-packages?** Hence, line one should do the trick - line  two shouldn't be needed? If it doesn't: then **what's the true purpose/usage of the asterix?**

For example, using `SELECT * FROM foo` in MySQL selects ALL fields from a table, perhaps I'm stupid to assume that this naturally is t he case.

Comment: It's used to import all the classes in the given package (i.e. all classes in `java.awt`), not the sub-packages and their classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, packages are taken as a whole. Even though it's often useful to think of them hierarchically, there is no notion within the Java language or compilation that says `java.awt.event` *belongs to* `java.awt`.

Your comparison with SQL tables isn't quite right because there's no such thing as a sub-table in SQL databases. Instead, imagine you had a table representing all your classes, with the following entries:

```
ID | Package   | Name
--------------------------
1  | awt       | SomeClassName1
2  | awt.event | SomeClassName2
```

Now, if you wanted to get awt classes, you'd say:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Package = 'awt'
```

You wouldn't expect this to give you both entries, just because the package name *starts with* `awt`, would you?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834602/is-this-how-java-package-imports-are-supposed-to-work/11834637#11834637) (and my comment). A wildcard only goes 1 level deep, not into subpackages

Answer (score 0):

Each package name ("a.b.c") is a discrete package. Two packages with similar naming prefix ("a.b.c" and "a.b.d", for example) are separate packages for the language, both for namespaces  and for access control.

For humans, of course, this represents a possible relation between the packages.