# Cannot find symbol Line2D?

Tags: java, awt

I can't understand why I'm getting the following error - `cannot find symbol - class Line2D` - when I try to compile this code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class KochSegment
{
    public Line2D base = new Line2D(); public Line2D[] Lines = new Line2D[4]; //error is on this line

etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in a subpackage:

```
java.awt.geom.Line2D
```

So you'd need either

```
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
```

or

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm such a noob

Comment: @RenéG We've all been there! Also, just FYI you may want to consider not using wildcard imports ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad

Comment: Why doesn't awt.* import geom?

Comment: In that question the asker used awt.*

Comment: @RenéG Right, packages are treated as a whole so subpackages are not imported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131195/shouldnt-import-foo-also-include-subpackage-foo-bar

Answer (score 3):

Some lessons that should be learned from this:

1. Star imports **only** import classes from a package.  They do not import from sub-packages as well.  In fact, sub-packages in Java are *purely syntactic*.  As far as the Java language is concerned, there is NO semantic relationship between classes in different packages or sub-packages.
2. Star imports tend to obscure problems.  A lot of people recommend not using them.  Write the imports out in full.  Or better still, use an IDE that can do classname completion, and generate missing imports.  (Granted, you do need to be a bit careful when for example the IDE offers you multiple completions for (say) `Date` or `List`.)
3. Searching and reading the javadoc is a good way to help with problems like this.  A javadoc search (or a class list scan) would tell you what the fully qualified name for the `Line2D` class is.